# How to load a certificate with private key from PEM files in .NET standard

Tags: x509certificate, .net-standard

I'm trying to load an X509Certificate2 from PEM files in a .NET standard library.

I created a self-signed certificate using openssl like so:

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -nodes -subj /CN=localhost -days 365
```

I loaded the resulting PEM files into embedded string resources within the project and am trying to load them with the following code:

```
private X509Certificate2 GetCertificate()
{
    try
    {
        byte[] pubPem = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Properties.Resources.DefaultPublicPem.Trim());
        var cert = new X509Certificate2(pubPem);
        var rsa = GetRSAFromPem(Properties.Resources.DefaultPrivatePem.Trim());
        cert.PrivateKey = rsa;
        return cert;
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // ignore errors
        return null;
    }
}

public static RSA GetRSAFromPem(String pemstr)
{
    RSA rsaKey = RSA.Create();
    Func<RSA, RsaKeyParameters, RSA> MakePublicRCSP = (RSA rcsp, RsaKeyParameters rkp) =>
    {
        RSAParameters rsaParameters = DotNetUtilities.ToRSAParameters(rkp);
        rcsp.ImportParameters(rsaParameters);
        return rsaKey;
    };

    Func<RSA, RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters, RSA> MakePrivateRCSP = (RSA rcsp, RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters rkp) =>
    {
        RSAParameters rsaParameters = DotNetUtilities.ToRSAParameters(rkp);
        rcsp.ImportParameters(rsaParameters);
        return rsaKey;
    };

    PemReader reader = new PemReader(new StringReader(pemstr));
    object kp = reader.ReadObject();

    // If object has Private/Public property, we have a Private PEM
    var hasPrivate = kp.GetType().GetProperty("Private") != null;
    var isPrivate = kp is RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters;
    return isPrivate ? MakePrivateRCSP(rsaKey, (RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters)kp) : hasPrivate ? MakePrivateRCSP(rsaKey, (RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters)(((AsymmetricCipherKeyPair)kp).Private)) : MakePublicRCSP(rsaKey, (RsaKeyParameters)kp);
}
```

I tested it on Android and it works great.

On iOS I haven't tested yet, but on UWP it fails and I get a PlatformNotSupported Exception while trying to set the PrivateKey on the certificate.

So I'm wondering what's not supported, and whether I'm not doing it right.

Answer (score 3):

According to [this](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/14284), setting the private key on an existing certificate is not supported in .net core:

> The PrivateKey property will be back in netstandard2.0 (#12295), but
>   it will throw on set for .NET Core.
>
> set_PrivateKey has a large amount of nuance in .NET Framework
>   (depending on how you use it you can end up with side effects that
>   persist across machine reboots), and mirroring that level of nuance to
>   platforms other than Windows is awfully tricky, which is why we don't
>   support it.
>
> The only supported way to have a cert with a private key on .NET Core
>   is through a PFX/PKCS12 file (or the cert+key pair to already be
>   associated via X509Store).

So one way to solve this was to merge public-private pair to a PFX file, embed it as a resource, and initialize the X509Certificate2 from that PFX.

Another way, which I ended up using, is to use the method RSACertificateExtensions.CopyWithPrivateKey on UWP.

So basically I ended up building a platform specific interface for loading the certificates. On UWP it was implemented like this:

```
public class UWPCertificateBuilder : ICertificateBuilder
{
    public X509Certificate2 GetCertificate(X509Certificate2 cert, RSA key)
    {
        return cert.CopyWithPrivateKey(key);
    }
}
```

On Android it was implemented like this:

```
public class DroidCertificateBuilder : ICertificateBuilder
{
    public X509Certificate2 GetCertificate(X509Certificate2 cert, RSA key)
    {
        cert.PrivateKey = key;
        return cert;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, `CopyWithPrivateKey` is the way to go.  It works on .NET Core and .NET Framework, but apparently not on Mono.

Comment: What is the definition of CopyWithPrivateKey metthod?

Comment: `CopyWithPrivateKey()` will instantiate a new CSP. As an example `UseMachineKeyStore`-flag cannot be set during the operation making the key not accessible for other processes.

Comment: Any update on this? 
I can put my per cert and key files into appsettings.json but tryint to do the same thing in code has been a shit-show.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `RSACryptoServiceProvider` you should use base `RSA` class. In .NET Standard and .NET Core on Windows, RSA private key is resolved to `RSACng`, instead of legacy `RSACryptoServiceProvider`.

See this thread for more details: [X509AsymmetricSecurityKey.GetAsymmetricAlgorithm returns null after .Net 4.7.2 upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53535972/x509asymmetricsecuritykey-getasymmetricalgorithm-returns-null-after-net-4-7-2-u)

Comment: Thanks. So I changed the code to use RSACng as you advised, but I'm still getting the same error... I've edited the question to reflect this change.