# Error setting X509Certificate2 PrivateKey

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am migrating a .NetFramework 4.6.1 library to a .NetCore 2.2.
But i am unable to set x509certificate.PrivateKey as shown below.

I have read that may be due to the RSAServiceProvider but i am unaware how to set this property. Even instantiating: 
 x509certificate.PrivateKey = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
throws the PlatformNotSupportedException.

```
// selfsign certificate
Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate certificate = 
certificateGenerator.Generate(signatureFactory);

// correponding private key
PrivateKeyInfo info = 
PrivateKeyInfoFactory.CreatePrivateKeyInfo(subjectKeyPair.Private);

// merge into X509Certificate2
var x509certificate = new X509Certificate2(certificate.GetEncoded());

Asn1Sequence seq = (Asn1Sequence)
Asn1Object.FromByteArray(info.ParsePrivateKey().GetDerEncoded() 
);

RsaPrivateKeyStructure rsa = RsaPrivateKeyStructure.GetInstance(seq);
RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters rsaParams = new 
RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters(
rsa.Modulus,
rsa.PublicExponent,
rsa.PrivateExponent,
rsa.Prime1,
rsa.Prime2,
rsa.Exponent1,
rsa.Exponent2,
rsa.Coefficient);

x509certificate.PrivateKey = DotNetUtilities.ToRSA(rsaParams);
```

In the .NetCore library setting x509certificate.PrivateKey with the RSA from DotNetUtilities.ToRSA(rsaParams) throws an PlatformNotSupportedException.

```
System.PlatformNotSupportedException
  HResult=0x80131539
  Message=Operation is not supported on this platform.
  Source=System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates
  StackTrace:
   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2.set_PrivateKey(AsymmetricAlgorithm value)
```

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/3c30357d51b96339021b4ee52f38445c31248bb2/src/System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates/src/System/Security/Cryptography/X509Certificates/X509Certificate2.cs#L196 That's by design. Why do you want to change private key? In most cases you should construct another certificate instead.

Comment: @LexLi because it`s a migration from an existing library. Did the design changed from .NetFramework to .NetCore, since it was possible to set the PrivateKey when creating a new certicate. As is: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17409271/10311071

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As LexLi said, setting the private key on an existing certificate is not possible by design in .net core.

Following what is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53593782/10311071), what you can do is use the method RSACertificateExtensions.CopyWithPrivateKey.

Instead of

```
x509certificate.PrivateKey = DotNetUtilities.ToRSA(rsaParams);
```

you could have

```
var rsa = DotNetUtilities.ToRSA(rsaParams);
var cert = x509certificate.CopyWithPrivateKey(rsa);
return cert;
```

To get access to the "CopyWithPrivateKey" extension method, add this using :

```
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates; /* for getting access to extension methods in RSACertificateExtensions */
```

> "(CopyWithPrivateKey) Combines a private key with the public key of an RSA certificate to
>   generate a new RSA certificate."

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.rsacertificateextensions.copywithprivatekey?view=netcore-3.0

Comment: See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.rsacertificateextensions?view=netcore-3.0

Answer (score 2):

The provided solution did not help me, so I'll be leaving this solution here hoping it will help the next person having this problem.

Using CertBuilder().ConvertBouncyCert it's possible to convert a BouncyCastle X509Certificate to a X509Certificate2 with the public/private key embedded.

```
X509Certificate2 _x509certificate2 = new CertBuilder().ConvertBouncyCert(_bouncyCertificate, subjectKeyPair);
```

And the full example i'm using it in (based on the answer provided here: [Bouncy Castle's X509V3CertificateGenerator.SetSignatureAlgorithm marked obsolete. What do I do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36712679/bouncy-castles-x509v3certificategenerator-setsignaturealgorithm-marked-obsolete)).

```
        public static X509Certificate2 CreateSelfSignedCertificateBasedOnCertificateAuthorityPrivateKey(string ipAddress, string issuerName, AsymmetricKeyParameter issuerPrivKey)
    {
        const int keyStrength = 4096;

        // Generating Random Numbers            
        CryptoApiRandomGenerator randomGenerator = new CryptoApiRandomGenerator();
        SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom(randomGenerator);
        ISignatureFactory signatureFactory = new Asn1SignatureFactory("SHA512WITHRSA", issuerPrivKey, random);
        // The Certificate Generator
        X509V3CertificateGenerator certificateGenerator = new X509V3CertificateGenerator();
        certificateGenerator.AddExtension(X509Extensions.ExtendedKeyUsage, true, new ExtendedKeyUsage((new List<DerObjectIdentifier>() { new DerObjectIdentifier("1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1"), new DerObjectIdentifier("1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2") })));

        // Serial Number
        BigInteger serialNumber = BigIntegers.CreateRandomInRange(BigInteger.One, BigInteger.ValueOf(Int64.MaxValue), random);
        certificateGenerator.SetSerialNumber(serialNumber);

        // Issuer and Subject Name
        X509Name subjectDN = new X509Name("CN=" + ipAddress);
        X509Name issuerDN = new X509Name(issuerName);
        certificateGenerator.SetIssuerDN(issuerDN);
        certificateGenerator.SetSubjectDN(subjectDN);

        // Valid For
        DateTime notBefore = DateTime.UtcNow.Date;
        DateTime notAfter = notBefore.AddYears(2);

        certificateGenerator.SetNotBefore(notBefore);
        certificateGenerator.SetNotAfter(notAfter);

        // Subject Public Key
        AsymmetricCipherKeyPair subjectKeyPair;
        var keyGenerationParameters = new KeyGenerationParameters(random, keyStrength);
        var keyPairGenerator = new RsaKeyPairGenerator();
        keyPairGenerator.Init(keyGenerationParameters);
        subjectKeyPair = keyPairGenerator.GenerateKeyPair();

        certificateGenerator.SetPublicKey(subjectKeyPair.Public);

        GeneralNames subjectAltName = new GeneralNames(new GeneralName(GeneralName.IPAddress, ipAddress));
        certificateGenerator.AddExtension(X509Extensions.SubjectAlternativeName, false, subjectAltName);

        // self sign certificate
        Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate certificate = certificateGenerator.Generate(signatureFactory);

        X509Certificate2 certificate2 = new CertBuilder().ConvertBouncyCert(certificate, subjectKeyPair);
        return certificate2;
    }
```

Used nuget packages:

- Portable.BouncyCastle by Oren Novotny version 1.8.5
- CryptLink.CertBuilder by Jermy Peterson version 1.1.0

Comment: As far as I can tell, `CertBuilder` is not part of `Portable.BouncyCastle`. Where is it comming from?

Comment: CertBuilder is part of CryptLink.CertBuilder by Jermy Peterson (version 1.1.0). I seem to have mist this package, must have been added somewhere along the line when testing the code. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: This code works for windows but not supporting to linux.